# Random Item generator based on Select Drop Down

Tags: javascript, html, generator

So I am trying to build a item generator that is specific based on the 3 selections of a drop down option.
The goal is based on the location and rarity that is selected, you can then randomly generate an item from that selection.
For example, if from the drop down you choose Amaryllis, Flower Field, and Common, you would then get a random item generated from the const list, flowerfieldCommon.
I'm relevantly new to coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
  Subjects: <select name="affiliation" id="affiliation">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select affiliation</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Topics: <select name="location" id="location">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select subject first</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Chapters: <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select topic first</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
</form>


    <script>
const flowerfieldCommon = ["Poppies", "Achillea millefolium", "Aconit", "Anemone hupehensis", "Roman Chamomile", "Amaryllis belladona", "Mystery amaryllis orchid", "Wooden Stick", "Plants stems", "Long green grass", "Dandelion"];

const flowerfieldRare = ["Agapanthus Blue Heaven", "Allium", "SunFlower", "Buddleia", "Alpine Aster", "Blueberries", "Piece of wooden bark", "Solidified resin", "Dahlia", "Rose", "Alkekengi", "Hortensia", "Wild carrots", "Red vine", "Mirabilis jalapa", "Little knotweed Root"];

var affiliationObject = {
  "Amaryllis": {
    "Flower Field": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "Seashore Beach": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "Rivers and Falls": ["Common", "Rare"]
  },
  "Sarikhra": {
    "DG": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "Cavern": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "Beach": ["Common", "Rare"]
  },
  "Loner": {
    "PMW": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "OS": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "Desert": ["Common", "Rare"],
    "VC": ["Common", "Rare"]
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var affiliationSel = document.getElementById("affiliation");
  var locationSel = document.getElementById("location");
  var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chapter");
  for (var x in affiliationObject) {
    affiliationSel.options[affiliationSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  affiliationSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    chapterSel.length = 1;
    locationSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in affiliationObject[this.value]) {
      locationSel.options[locationSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
  locationSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters dropdown
    chapterSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    var z = affiliationObject[affiliationSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      chapterSel.options[chapterSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}


    </script>
    <div id="quoteDisplay">
  </div>
<button onclick="newQuote()">Generate Item</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function newQuote() {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (selectedItem.length));
      document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = selectedItem[randomNumber];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I tried making another If else statement, but I scraped it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.